# View won't load JS in Rails 4 application on page change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Bear with me as I'm rather new to Rails and have very little experience with JS.

I purchased a Bootstrap theme for my rails app and I'm running into an issue with the JS written. It's not loading various scripts due to turbolinks but I have no idea on how to resolve this. Here's the JS file that came with the theme.

Theme.JS file:

```
    (function ($) {
            "use strict";




            $(window).load(function () {
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
                // SITE LOADER                     ||-----------
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
                $('#loader').fadeOut();
                $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
                $('body').delay(350).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });


            })


            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            // GENERAL SCRIPTS FOR ALL PAGES    ||-----------
            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


            $(document).ready(function () {

                openSite();

            });




            function openSite() {
                fullScreenSlider();
                header();
                scroll();
                winResize();
                pushmenu();
                pluginElement();
                sliderHero();
                sliderAll();
                containerGridMasonry();
                scrollCallbackEle();
                shortcodeElements();

            };



            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            // RESIZE FUNCTIONS   ||-----------
            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

            function winResize() {

                $(window).resize(function () {

                })
            };



    })(jQuery);
```

I've messed around with

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function(){
  fullScreenSlider();
  header();
  scroll();
  winResize();
  pushmenu();
  pluginElement();
  sliderHero();
  sliderAll();
  containerGridMasonry();
  scrollCallbackEle();
  shortcodeElements();
});`
```

As well as just running `page:load` around the OpenSite function around just the Jquery part, around all the functions. I'm really at a loss here, not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've used the turbolinks Gem and I thought that had it fixed but after a page reload only a couple things work on the page.

Here's a list of functions that seem to work after clicking a link that changes the view.

header()

sliderAll()

skillsProgressBar()

accordion()

> accordion() is intermittent and I have no idea why it works when nothing else is working. It never really worked but started working when everything else broke.

Any ideas would be most appreciated. I'm probably doing plenty wrong here but, like I said, I'm new and taking a class on this but we are almost at the end of the semester and haven't even covered Gems.

PS. I know I need to have the functions run off of a page change rather than document.ready but I have been trying to figure it out for almost a week to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also a jquery rails gem that fixes some of the things. But the easiest solution is to probably just remove turbolinks.

Comment: I've installed the jQuery Turbolinks Gem and only part of the JS loads properly. So a temporary fix would be to remove the gem and the turbolinks reference from the application.js manifest? I'd rather find a fix on how to make this work as site load times and long term knowledge is worthwhile for me. Thank you for the heads up, if I can't get it resolved I'll try that route as a temporary fix.

Comment: Made the changes and your solution works. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think this is something others have struggled with and I've seen long threads on fixing this but I believe the solutions out there are incomplete unfortunately. If you end up finding a way to fix it let me know. I think turbolinks is something that's here to stay.